# BCP Error Numeric value out of range when importing multi-line file to Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, data-warehouse, bcp, azure-synapse

I'm trying to load my Azure SQL Data Warehouse using the bcp utility but have been running into issue after issue...I finally got a .txt file with one record to import successfully, but now when I put two or more records into the file, it bombs out with the error (via an error output file):

> Row 1, Column 5: Numeric value out of range

The data looks like this:

```
2014-06-01,11111,test,used,1
2014-06-01,22222,test,used,1
```

and the table I'm importing to looks like this:

```
[Date] (date, not null)
[Code] (varchar(50), not null)
[Model] (varchar(100), not null)
[Type] (varchar(20), not null)
[Quantity] (int, not null)
```

I think it has something to do with the new line character but I haven't been able to work around it.  I have tried changing the encoding in Notepad++ to ANSI, ISO-8859-1, UTF-8 w/o BOM, as well as UTF-16 LE & BE with Visual Studio CODE.  When 'ANSI' was specified, the one-line file imported successfully.  The end-of-line sequence is set to LF, and my bcp command is as follows:

```
bcp Schema.Table in C:\BcpFiles\sourceData.txt -S serverName -d databaseName -U userName -P password -q -c -t "," -r/n -e C:\BcpFiles\Errors.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The -r parameter requires a back slash rather than forward: try -r \n instead. This article explains the various combinations: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms191485.aspx

UPDATE:

```
create table tst (
[Date] date not null,
[Code] varchar(50) not null,
[Model] varchar(100) not null,
[Type] varchar(20) not null,
[Quantity] int not null
)
```

And then using this:

bcp dbo.tst in so.txt -S TONYMSI -d AdventureWorks2012 -T -q -c -t "," -r \n

Worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  This however didn't resolve it for me.  It still works with one record, but when I add a line break (LF) the error is: "Invalid character value for cast specification" and still points to column 5 (the number 1 being inserted into an INT column).

Comment: Can you take a look at the update on my answer - works fine for me. That begs the question - can you script out the table you are trying to BCP into, the one in the database specified by -d, also note there is a space between -r and \n

Comment: Azure SQL Data Warehouse only supports BCP with UTF-8.  On your re-attempt, was the file in UTF-8?